# How to run external command in neovim on BufWritePre set in Lua

Tags: python, lua, neovim, python-black

I would like to format my code using `/bin/black` everytime I save a python file in `neovim`. So I have the following in my `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`

```
a.nvim_create_autocmd( { "BufWritePre" }, {
  pattern = { "*.py" },
  command = [[ /bin/black ]],
})
```

but I get the error like:

```
E492: Not an editor command:  /bin/black
```

Could someone let me know how can I run `black` (an external command) in `BufWritePre` set.

Cheers,
DD.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the question and I got it.

it command should be

```
a.nvim_create_autocmd( { "BufWritePre" }, {
  pattern = { "*.py" },
  command = [[ !/bin/black % ]],
})
```

where `!` for external command and `%` for current file.